# C# отправить POST запрос получить ответ затем отправить снова

Tags: c#, post, request, response

Доброе время суток,

Через ПОСТ-МАН я отправляю запрос на сайт с данными, затем получаю ответ от сайта 200ОК, после ответа сайт требует ввести данные еще одного поле, тут я не понимаю как на c# сделать так чтоб не прерывая сессию с кукисами отправить второй запрос ПОСТ, ведь на вторую страницу не попать если не ввел данные первой странице.

Иными словами, зайдя на сайт через браузер, нужно ввести данные в текстбоксы, после нажать на кнопку далее, после выходит еще одна страница где нужно ввести еще данные 1го текстбокса и нажать еще раз на далее.
пример.

1. https://site.com/send/type
   тут два текстбокса (ввели данные)
2. https://site.com/send/Success
   тут один текстбокс (ввели данные)

Мой код такой для 1й отправки ПОСТ запроса.

```
var client = new RestClient("https://site.com/send/page");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Cookie", "PHPSESSID=v9jbhg2btlps5vma4f3u276md5");
request.AlwaysMultipartFormData = true;
request.AddParameter("account", "41010913388000000000");
request.AddParameter("id", "17590207");
request.AddParameter("pay_type", "1");
request.AddParameter("email", "");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115482/discussion-on-question-by---c--post---).

Answer (score 2):

```
var client = new RestClient("https://site.com");
client.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
    
var response = client.Execute(new RestRequest("send/type", Method.POST));
var response2 = client.Execute(new RestRequest("send/Success", Method.POST));
```

Использование одного клиента RestClient с CookieContainer сохраняет ваши куки.
В коде пример вызова двух запросов без дополнительных свойств с одним клиентом.